# The TERM variable and Ssh connection

Tags: linux, ssh

Setting the `TERM` variable for ssh client (like `Putty`) does it impact only the client itself (how does it displays the outpt) or is it also send (the value of the var) to the server? If so what does the server have to do with it? Can you bring some examples?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you set `TERM` on PuTTY is to pass it to the server.  Applications running on the server use that environment variable to pick a *terminal description* which tells the application if the terminal supports color, how to set colors, what function-keys it might send and how to interpret the sequence of characters sent by each function-key.

PuTTY doesn't use `TERM` directly.

Comment: In this case what is the terminal? Is it just Putty client itsef?

Comment: yes, PuTTY is a terminal *emulator*.